# Using C++ and libcurl to log in the following webpage

Tags: c++, web, authentication, libcurl

I am trying to develop the auto mail retrieval application in C++.

I just want to know how can I use libcurl to log in the following webpage.

https://webmail.stanford.edu/

where it is redirected to some log in webpage for the authentication.

I am not sure how I can fill the form and send a request through the libcurl. Here's what I have tried.

I realized that log in web page consists following input fields;

- 2 hidden input fields named "RT" and "ST" (with value keys) --> I stored them in input_field map.
- 1 text input field for username
- 1 password input field for password

So I tried the following methods to send a POST request to the server.

```
    post_field.append("RT=").append(input_field["RT"]).append("&");
    post_field.append("ST=").append(input_field["ST"]).append("&");
    post_field.append("username=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASSWORD");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post_field);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

However it seems it is not working (I enabled cookie, SSL connection). All I just want to do is fill the form and press submit button through libcurl.

Edit;

After sending the POST request, the retrieved web page says

Error: The URL given is incomplete.

To try again, please return to the preceding web page (or you may need to start your request for this web service again). For help or to report a service problem, contact...

Comment: ‘Not working’ isn't a very good description of the problem. If you want help you'll have to be more detailed than that; read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, doesn't Stanford provide IMAP/POP?

Comment: Yeah but I actually wanted to implement the actual 'log in' step. There are others things I want to implement besides retrieving mails but using Stanford authentication.